# next/link is changing href attribute from relative to absolute

Tags: next.js, next-link

Using next/link

```
<Link href="/examples/fetch-rest-data" >
     <a>SWR</a>
</Link>
```

I get an absolute href on the HTML

```
<li>
    <a href="https://localhost/examples/fetch-rest-data">SWR</a>
</li>
```

But i need the html to have a relative href

```
<li>
    <a href="/examples/fetch-rest-data">SWR</a>
</li>
```

Comment: its should have relative path 
Try this:
`<Link href="/examples/fetch-rest-data" passHref>
     <a>SWR</a>
</Link>`

Comment: Same issue with `passHref`

Comment: Why do you need relative path?

Comment: If i'm not wrong is the correct behavior and to run automated tests for SEO that check the relative path for internal linking

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170595/relative-absolute-path-of-internal-links-for-seo-purpose

Comment: I know that but I need the relative href. We are migrating from a legacy server to next.js and already have tons of SEO tests. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: `next/link` will always output absolute URLs. You should refactor (or disable) your SEO tests to check for absolute URLs instead.